# Would towels under floorboards (for sound insulation) be considered an unacceptable fire risk?

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate

I am a live-in landlord (UK), with two lodgers. My bedroom is on the ground floor, my lodger is in the bedroom above me. I want to reduce the noise from above, and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pABvTWSxOes) suggests that folded towels make great sound-insulation.

I want to put some folded towels under the floorboards in my lodgers' room for this reason. However, most towels are 100% cotton and so burn quite well. Would I get into trouble for doing something like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would almost certainly be ***criminally liable*** if a fire were to occur and your insulation did not meet the [Fire Safety Building Regulations](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/485420/BR_PDF_AD_B1_2013.pdf), especially as you deliberately used a non-conforming material.

Cotton towels are not one of the materials that have met or exceeded the EU and UK regulations.

Edit to add - as an aside, should you suffer a fire for whatever reason, any landlord, housing or home insurance you have have will almost certainly become void should the insurance company discover your use of cotton towels as insulation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94389/discussion-on-answer-by-moo-would-towels-under-floorboards-for-sound-insulation).

Answer (score -1):

Let me preface this by saying I'm not a housing lawyer, but have done work on landlord tenant housing issues, particularly disrepair, so I believe I may weigh in here.

Anyway, generally speaking, you will be liable for any damage caused to the property of the lodgers, or to any injury and/or loss suffered by the lodgers as the *direct* result of the towels accelerating or exacerbating a fire that *you caused*.

What is important to note, is that you would be at fault here if a fire damages the tenants/their property only if:

1. The fire is negligently started by you (in this case, the existence of the towels would not matter)
2. A fire, that is not your fault - which would otherwise not have damaged the tenant's property or injured the tenants - ends up doing damage/harm to the tenants because of your towels.

What point 2 is saying is: even if the towels catch on fire and does damage, it would not necessarily be your fault, but the fault of the person who started the fire. The only time you would be in trouble for the damage caused by someone else's fire is if you towels are shown to be the reason why the fire spread to the tenants' rooms. This is awfully hypothetical, because generally, towels or not, a fire will spread.

I am unaware of any byelaws or statutes which forbid a person from insulating their house with whatever material they want.

From my research the regulations on insulation exist for builders of a house (See the [Building Regulations 2010](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2010/2214/contents/made)) - they can't just insulate a house with whatever they want. But you as landlord should not be limited by this, in my opinion. It is possible that your local council may have regulations to this effect, so it may be prudent to check in with them.

Towels are not inherently dangerous so unless you are stuffing your entire house with highly flammable towels I think you are relatively safe from a negligence claim.

Comment: Common sense is that if one answer says "You will pay dearly for it", and another answer says "No problem", then you either pay an expert who is legally responsibile for damage caused by giving wrong advise, or you act according to the first answer.

Comment: Well the most prudent response to any legal question would be to seek legal advice. But that doesn't mean advice amounting to "there's no problem here" is wrong. I think your comment doesn't add any value to the answer or point out why it is wrong (if at all). I'd be happy to change my answer if anyone can show me a statute which requires landowners to maintain their premises with an approved list of insulators, but I am not aware of any

Answer (score -4):

I don't think there is a specific case about towels in the floor you can compare it to, and there are no specific mentions of towels in the floor in the law obviously, so if you were sued it would be up to the jury to decide if that was reasonable or not.

The only real authority to talk to would be your local fire department. Even that does not stop someone from suing you though.

Comment: There are specific standards in section B2 of the law which linings must meet. Towels will not comply.

Comment: No offense to you, but there is just no way that is true. Movie theater's concert venues etc place materials in the ceilings to damper noise. You reading of it would make them all illegal.

Comment: Did you read section B2 of the law linked in the other answer? Have you read any modern building code or fire code? Standards for materials used are routine and do not include a list of specific forbidden materials. Yes materials are placed to damp noise. But they must comply with the standards, or else the operators are in violation, and may face penalties if caught. Some operators do violate standards.

Comment: If "no mention of towels in the law" means that towels are ok as insulation, does the lack of mention of gunpowder mean one can use that as insulation legally?

Comment: No of course not on the gun powder. If you read my answer I didn't say anything not mentioned is ok. You are trying to make it sound as if you can drag what I said out to say anything not in a law is ok.

Comment: Yes, I read section B2 and have read other building codes. I'm not from the UK, but while working for a sheriff's dept in IL, I have witnessed fire inspections when IL state level fire officials needed to be let into a building or escorted. Everywhere has there own standards, but I have literally witnessed IL fire inspectors be ok with placing towels in places to dampen noise. I'll admit they didn't pull up floors to stick them in, but here anyway, they focus on the insulation and flooring.

Comment: To be fair, your answer said that anything not specifically mentioned would be up to the Jury. I was trying to show that your logic leads to a nonsensical result, in my view. But in tis case the law specifically mentions linings complying with a specific test, measuring reduced speed of ignition  and heat of combustion, and said that only things that passed the specified test could be used.

Comment: I know what you mean, but saying that you would have to litigate some items does not mean you use gun powder or other obviously dangerous things. There's clearly a difference between putting explosives somewhere and using something that may not be the best materials. I'm not calling you ridiculous or anything derogatory, but to equate using some makeshift sound barriers is not the same as an explosive and any reasonable person would probably feel the same.

Comment: Also, if you use the logic that it is for sure illegal and want to follow everything to extremes, a kid dropping his towel on the floor in a hurry would have the same effect in that it would make it burn faster and then that kid would be criminally liable. That is just too extreme.

Comment: A towel dropped on the ground is obviously not being used as insulation. Sound proofing material follows other codes as well, and those are no more likely to be ignored. This whole answer basically argues that since towels aren't explicitly mentioned, you've got a chance of being fine. This is not true at all.

Comment: It's not that because towels are not mentioned @Nij. It's that the floor would burn regardless of there being a towl there or not, so you probably could not win a lawsuit.

Comment: The question is not whether it burns, but whether it burns worse, and by using a material to do a job that has not passed the prescribed test of that fact, criminal liability is immediate.

Comment: @Nij You would have to prove that the towel burning harmed you in some way though. I am not trying to be rude, but I have worked in the criminal justice system and at least in the US no one is arresting you for anything related to towels.

Comment: That's not how liability works. You used the towels when the regulations are clear that you must not - the proof is of itself. I am extremely doubtful that nobody has ever been arrested, charged and convicted for deliberately using substandard construction materials in the USA, your anecdotes notwithstanding.

Comment: @Nij people have been sued for it, but arrested is a different story. I don't know how to say it in a nicer way, but I don't see how you guys can not accept the views of someone who worked for a sheriff when it comes to what you can be arrested for... my state does not even have a statute that would cover that.

Comment: The answer by Moo has already indicated that criminal liability is attached to breaches of the relevant regulations. What your state does or does not have is totally and utterly irrelevant, because we're talking about the UK here. The personal story of someone from a jurisdiction that is totally different means nothing, and your history of using that excuse to claim righteousness against the literal letter of the law makes it worth even less.

Comment: I've never said anything against the law while pointing out several times people here have. I admit the jurisdictions are different but the law Moo cited is still not a criminal law. You can not charge someone under a civil law yet you use that in a comment saying I ignored the law...

Comment: And just saying this fits into this textbook definition of this is not how people are arrested, for the most part, irl. Theres a lot of judgement involved.

Comment: And you version of against the letter of the law is someone disagreeing with you because what you say must be right.