# Would EVA foam under the carpet be considered an unacceptable fire risk?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property

I'd like to put some EVA foam under the carpet (above the floorboards) on the first floor bedroom of my house, to dampen the sound of foot steps. The [fire safety building regulations](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/485420/BR_PDF_AD_B1_2013.pdf) (section B2) say that the provisions do not apply to upper layers of floors since they don't play a major part in the spread of fires. Does that mean it is ok to use or is there something else I am missing?

Also note that the bedroom is occupied by a lodger. I have two lodgers in total. It is not an HMO. I live in the UK.

Comment: Continuation of this question: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41582/would-towels-under-floorboards-for-sound-insulation-be-considered-an-unaccepta

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason why an [ordinary foam carpet pad](https://www.flooringinc.com/blog/carpet-padding-buying-guide/) won't work?  That presumably would be legal, since it's designed and widely used for that exact purpose.

Comment: Have you thought about asking on [DIY.SE]? They might have some other suggestions that you might not have thought of?